# What is an array of constant pointers in C?

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers, constants

Isn't the address of an array and thus of all its elements as well constant anyway?

And if so, in a declaration like:

```
char *const argv[]
```

isn't the `const` qualifier redundant?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

No, the `const` in `char *const argv[]` is not redundant.

First, `const` and "constant" are actually two different things in C, even though the `const` keyword is obviously derived from the word "constant". A *constant expression* is one that can be evaluated at compile time. `const` really means "read-only". For example:

```
const int r = rand();
```

is perfectly legal.

Yes, the address of an array -- like the address of any object -- is read-only. But that doesn't mean that the *value* of the array (which consists of the values of its elements) is read-only, any more than any other object is necessarily read-only.

Consider these three declarations:

```
char *arr1[10];
char *const arr2[10];
const char *arr3[10];
```

`arr1` is a 10-element array of pointers to `char`. You can modify the `char*` elements *and* you can modify the objects that those elements point to.

`arr2` is an array of `const` (read-only) pointers to `char`. That means that you can't modify the `char*` elements of the array (once they're initialized) -- but you can still modify the `char` objects or arrays that those elements point to.

And `arr3` is an array of pointers to `const char`; you can modify the array elements, but you can't modify what they point to.

Now the fact that you used the name `argv` suggests that you're talking about the second parameter to `main`, which has some huge effects on this. The language specifies that `main`'s second parameter is

```
char *argv[]
```

or, equivalently,

```
char **argv
```

There is no `const`. You can *probably* get away with adding one, but it's best to follow the form specified by the standard. (Update: I see from your comment that you're asking about the `argv` parameter of `getopt()`, which is defined as `char * const argv[]`.)

And since it's a parameter defined as an array, another rule comes into play: a parameter defined as an array of some type is "adjusted" to a pointer to that type. (This rule applies *only* to parameters.) This isn't a run-time conversion. A function cannot have a parameter of array type.

The relationship between arrays and pointers in C can be confusing -- and there's a lot of misinformation out there. The most important thing to remember is that *arrays are not pointers*.

Section 6 of the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://www.c-faq.com/) is an excellent explanation of the details.

Comment: WHere by "read only" you actually mean "write only once", correct?

Comment: @Keith Thompson Thank you for your excellent detailed answer. It not only answered my question and completely cleared the confusion, but also points to some other very cool facts (about the arguments of main being adjusted for example), that I hadn't thought about. (My doubt didn't originate from main() though, it was from the library getopt function: int getopt(int argc, char * const argv[], const char *optstring).) Thank you!

Comment: @EricLippert: By "read only" I mean that the object cannot be modified by referring to its name. A `const` object can be initialized. You can't modify it by assigning a value to it -- not even once. `const int n = 42;` is valid; `const int n; n = 42;` is not.

Comment: @KeithThompson You wrote "And arr3 is an array of pointers" but arr defined as: const char *arr3. Is there a mistake?

Comment: @StavAlfi: There was. I've just fixed it. Thanks for catching that!

Comment: @KeithThompson Thank you, you wrote an excellent explanation!

Answer (score 5):

> Isn't the address of an array and thus of all its elements as well
>   constant anyway?

Yes, and it is true for any object in `C`. Recall that by object here, we mean a location in memory having a value and referenced by an identifier. The identifier is bound to a fixed memory location throughout its scope and you cannot change it. You can change the value of the object though.

```
int a = 4;
a = 6;  // legal. you can change the value of the object
&a = 23456; // illegal. you cannot change the address of the object
```

Similarly, an array is also an object and each of its elements will have a fixed memory address. However, the value held by an element of the array has nothing to do with the address of the element.

Note that if the declaration appears in a function parameter list, then the following are equivalent

```
char *const argv[]
char *const *argv
```

which means that `argv` is a pointer to an object which is of type `char *const`, i.e., a constant pointer to a character. It's obvious that `char *const *argv` and `char **argv` are different. So let's take another example.

```
char *const argv[10];
```

The above statement defines `argv` to be an array of `10` constant pointers to a character. This means that you have to initialize the array and cannot later change the pointers to point to a different character. However, this has nothing to do with the address of the array elements.

```
char c = 'A';
char d = 'B';
char *const argv[2] = {&c, &d}; 

argv = &c; // illegal. you cannot the change the address of an object
argv[0] = &d; // illegal. you cannot change the value of the array element
*argv[0] = 'C'; // legal. you change the value pointed to by the element
```

Without the `const` qualifier, `char *argv[2]` means an array of `2` pointers to characters.
This is clearly different from the case when we have the `const` qualifier as explained above. Therefore, to answer your second question, no, the `const` qualifier is not redundant. That's because the `const` qualifier qualifies the type of the array elements.

Comment: Thank you for your excellent clarification and valuable additional pointers!

Answer (score 2):

No, it isn't. `char *const argv[]` is an array of constant pointers to `char`. So the `const` makes the pointers in the array constant (you cannot change them to point to other strings in memory).